# Scanning from the console

Tags: java, console

In java, to scan from the console, why are different ways used and what do they mean? 
What is the difference between using Scanner class and Stream class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Scanner reads primitive types as you can see below:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i = sc.nextInt();
```

Now `i`is for example a `3`.

Stream class is a bit more complex. I recommend, if you want to read, for example, integers in normal programs, like "Tell me your age" stuff, use scanner. Stream is reading bytes and converting them manually.

```
 dis = new DataInputStream(is);
 while(dis.available()>0) {

            // read four bytes from data input, return int
            int k = dis.readInt();

            // print int
            System.out.print(k+" ");
         }
```